# How to push a string in stack?

Tags: c, string, stack, push

How to push a string in stack,

I have used these structures to develop a stack to store students details and their marks,

```
   typedef struct node{
        char name[50];
        int marks;
        struct node * next;
    }Node;

    typedef struct{
        int no_student;
        Node * top;
    }stack;
```

My Push function to push his name and marks into the stack is below,

```
void Push(stack *S, char name[], int marks){
    Node *np;
    np = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    np->marks = marks;
    strcpy(S->top->name, name);
    np->next = S->top;
    S->top = np;
    S->no_student++;
}
```

When I run this code, Compiler giving me a run time error, How can I fix this?

Comment: don't cast the result of `*alloc()`.

Comment: `sizeof(np)` is the size of the *pointer* `np`, not the structure it (will) point to. You need to use `sizeof *np`.

Comment: Instead of sizeof(np) in malloc, you should write sizeof(Node)

Comment: There are other problems with your code as well, I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: This looks more like a linked list than a stack IMHO.

Comment: @babon Linked lists are the simplest way of creating a stack without specific limits.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude last time i checked rubber ducks were out of stock. might be the reason we are seing such mediocre questions here lately.

Comment: Bro, when I try to debug this code, it's giving me the error is on `strcpy(S->top->name, name);`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My idea was that stack is a block of memory which one fills and releases from one end. If a bigger space is required, call up `realloc`... Somehow I felt like a stack should be a single chunk and should not be scattered all over the place

Comment: `strcpy(S->top->name, name);` shouldn't be `strcpy(np->name, name);`? Trying to copy new name on old top of stack will fail at beginning when the stack is empty and `S->top==NULL`.

Comment: @Frankie_C, You are right thanks for your help